# crossfilter.js, how to deal with artificial duplicates on a date dimension

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

Im working on a rails project. The data structure looks like the following. a session can have many events.

```
[{"id":102,"user_id":"user_2","date":"2015-10-08","count":2,"duration":0,"events":[{"event_type":"Event1","reference_id":"23","duration":2},{"event_type":"Event2","reference_id":"22","duration":3}]}
```

Given the above datastructure i can generate graphs based on the session_date and so on. But i do need to generate piecharts based on data inside the nested events array (by event_type or reference_id for instance).

Now i did some reading and it seems that crossfilter works best on a a flat data structure. So i flatend the structure so that every event gets it own row.

```
[{"id":102,"date":"2015-10-08","count":2,"duration":0,"event_type":"Event1","reference_id":"23","user_id":"user_1","event_duration":2},{"id":102,"date":"2015-10-08","count":2,"duration":0,"event_type":"Event2","reference_id":"22","user_id":"user_2","duration":3}]
```

I no longer have problems using the data of the former event jsonarray. 
But now im having the following problem, i need a bar chart showing the number of sessions per day. In the above example i would have one Session with two events at 2015/10/8.

I created the date dimension like this:

```
var dateDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
             return d.date;
          });
```

And used to group like this:

```
var dateGroup = dateDimension.group();
```

I initialize the charts like this:

```
visitorBarChart.width(800)
                  .height(250)
                  .dimension(dateDimension).group(dateGroup)
                  .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
                  .xAxisLabel("Date")
                  .yAxisLabel("Visitors");
```

But obviously, since i have duplicate dates in the record this does not work any longer. its pretty much counting the number of events by date.

I need something like a group(date,id).count.

Im completely new to crossfilter and dc.js, i hope i described the problem accurately. I searched the web for hours now but i cant figure this one out.

Im guessing i have to do some work with reduceAdd/reduceRemove but i cant figure it out

Any help would be appreciated!

Alright i might have found an solution myself. Im calling reduce with the following functions on my group.

```
function reduceInitial() {
              return {
                  unique: d3.map(),
                  count: 0
              };
          }
          function reduceAdd(p, v) {
              var id = v.id;
              var date = v.date;
              //is there a date for the current id?
              var check = p.unique.get(id);
              // nopes add to count, add date to id
              if(!check){
                  ++p.count;
                  p.unique.set(id,date);
              }else{
                  //mhhh that should not be neccessary
                  if(check != date){
                      ++p.count;
                      p.unique.set(id,date);
                  }
              }
              //console.log(v)
              //console.log("---")
              //console.log(p)
              return p;
          }

          function reduceRemove(p, v) {
              var id = v.id;
              var date = v.date;
              var check = p.unique.get(id);
              if(check){
                  if(check == date){
                      p.unique.remove(id);
                      --p.count;
                  }

              }
              return p;
          }
```

I guess i could just use an array instead of d3.map, but seems to work for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just about got it, but you also need to track the number of each date you've seen for each ID and only add to the count for the first one you see and remove from the count if there are no more of that date.

I'll shill for [Reductio](https://github.com/esjewett/reductio), as most of the reason I built it is to make these complex and computationally expensive aggregations easier to do right and efficiently. What you want to do is what I call [exception aggregation](https://github.com/esjewett/reductio#exception-aggregation). With Reductio you would do:

```
var group = dateDimension.group();
var reducer = reductio()
    .exception(function(d) { return d.id; })
    .exceptionCount(true);

reducer(group);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Ethan. Thank you for the reply! Reductio looks really nice. But im not quite sure how to use it yet. If i try your code i get the following exception: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bisect' of undefined(anonymous function) @ reductio.js?body=1:1087`

Comment: That's interesting. Do all your records have ids? If not, you'll want to make sure they are at least all defined. If you want to put together an example, I'd be happy to look at it.

Comment: my bad.. i included reductio before crossfilter and dc. works like a charm now. I even fixed one of the piecharts, which had a similar problem within a minute :)